# Power of supplied by generator when it is loading

Tags: generator

I have a cummins generator which is having capacity in name plate as 803 kw. While running the load test, each phase current shows 153 A, 53 A, 120 A and neutral current 27 A or something. How can i calculate the power supplied by the generator using equation. Should i take the max current and use 1.73 x Vl x Il x pf or should i sum up all current and find. Please help with the equation, like which current i should take as I. This meter is showing phase current or line current. If in case of phase current what should i do or in case of line current what should i do?

Comment: A generator is rated in kVA. kW is an engine rating. Is your load test for the generator, or the engine?

Comment: Any decent electrical text book containing 3 phase power will give you the equations that you need.

Answer (score 0):

Convert the three phase problem into a single phase problem.

Have a look at this example:

[image]

Source: https://myelectrical.com/notes/entryid/8/three-phase-power-simple-calculations